# Angular retrieve data from json using index name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to access the view of user item from json array dealerLst. I am having problem in accessing multiple users from the below complex json. Can anyone help me how to access all children using angular or through typescript? Also how can  know that which children belong to which parent.

My code:
[Click to view my json output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5GgL.png)

Typescript code

```
 this.http.get<any>(environment.baseurl,{ headers }).subscribe({
      next: data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.dealers = data.dealerLst
        console.log(data.dealerLst.user)
        this.total=data.total
        
    },
    error: error => {
        console.error('There was an error!', error.message);
    }
    });
```

The result shows undefined. I also tried to put in ngFor loop but didn't work.

Comment: Where is it showing undefined? And what is the result supposed to be?

Comment: `data.dealerLst` is an array, you need to loop thru the array somehow to get the `user` property from each array item. I don't know what you're doing with the data, so I can't tell what your issue is from this

Comment: Can you copy your html code here?

Comment: My main purpose is to show both `dealerLst` and `user` in html page. Since each `user` is under each `dealerLst`, I can only show `dealerLst` in html, I am unable to retrieve which `user` belong to which `dealerLst`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your html looks a like this?

```
<div *ngFor="let dealer of dealers"> Dealer Id: {{dealer?.id}} user: {{dealer?.user?.loginName}}</div>
```

In your ts file:

```
this.http.get<any>(environment.baseurl,{ headers }).subscribe({
      next: data: <YOUR_INTERFACE> => {
        console.log(data)
        this.dealers = data.dealerLst
        console.log(data.dealerLst.user)
        this.total=data.total
        
    },
    error: error => {
        console.error('There was an error!', error.message);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Exact answer I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @AungPyae - I'm glad that, I was able to Help. I would like to suggest if you can define interface for your data in ts file, see my edited answer with your given code.